# Pointer to a std::unique_ptr of derived class from base class

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, smart-pointers, std

I am trying to make a `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>*` that can point to any `std::unique_ptr<DerivedClass>`.

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
[InputHandler] <--inherits from-- [DrawingTool] <--inherits from-- [ToolName]
```

And the following code:

```
std::unique_ptr<DrawingTool> *active_tool;
active_tool = tool_manager.getCurTool();   // Returns a unique_ptr<DrawingTool>*

std::unique_ptr<InputHandler> *cur_input_handler = active_tool;
```

However this gives the error:

```
 error: cannot convert ‘std::unique_ptr<DrawingTool>*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<InputHandler>*’ in initialization
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why would you have a pointer to `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: It sounds like you either want a raw pointer or a `shared_ptr`. It doesn't seem like you want to take ownership of the tool, so `DrawingTool * active_tool;` will probably be more useful here.

Comment: Do note that `some_template_type<T>` is a completely different type from `some_template_type<U>`.

Comment: @NutCracker I'm quite new to C++ so maybe I'm taking the wrong approach - but my thinking was that I don't want to share ownership of the class (with a raw pointer or shared_ptr), I just want to reference a class that is owned elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I suggest you to move on to the `std::shared_ptr` because `want to reference a class that is owned elsewhere` means that you should really use `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @JShorthouse: "*I just want to reference a class that is owned elsewhere.*" But that's just passing a reference. Or a raw pointer.

Comment: @JShorthouse please take a look at the answer I have written and provide me with some feedback, i.e. accept it if it helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference an object which is owned elsewhere in your code, [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is your way to go (at least if you want to achieve what you are showing in the example which is part of your question). Then, if you want to downcast base class `std::shared_ptr` to a derived class `std::shared_ptr` you can do the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base {};

struct Derived : Base {};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> base = std::make_shared<Base>();
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived = std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(base);

    return 0;
}
```

Furthermore, following code may mimic your situation and what you want to achieve a bit better:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base {};

struct Derived : Base {};

std::unique_ptr<Base> const& get_unique_ptr() {
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> base = std::make_unique<Base>();
    return base;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> const& base = get_unique_ptr();
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> derived(static_cast<Derived*>(base.get()));

    return 0;
}
```

Note that above solution may lead to unwanted behavior of releasing the same pointer twice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after thinking about this some more I think perhaps just using a raw pointer might be the best solution as another commenter suggested. What do you think? Your shared_ptr solution is nice but I think that it conveys the wrong intention. I never want the main class to own the object. To me using a shared_ptr suggests that both classes would have equal ownership. Also in your second solution, I may be missing something but are you saying that both unique_ptrs should point to the same value? Doesn't that make them unsafe and defeat the whole purpose of them?

Comment: Also as I said before I am quite new to C++ so please feel free to correct any of my wrong assumptions.

Comment: I think that you should go for `std::shared_ptr` solution because using raw pointers in modern C++ is not considered a best practice. And yes, second solution might lead to unwanted behavior of releasing the same pointer twice at the end of main. I forgot to add that to my answer

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, I will switch to using shared pointers then.